# How to transfer data into remote file over SFTP without storing data in a local file in Linux Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos, sftp

I need to be able to transfer data from memory into a remote file through SFTP. I originally had this working through SSH, and while working, discovered that I don't have SSH access to the remote location, only SFTP access.

Here is an example of the original SSH code I had:

```bash
echo "secret_data" | ssh root@localhost cat > secret_file;
```

This is exactly what I need, but in some kind of form of:

```bash
sftp root@localhost put $secret_data secret_file;
```

In principal, I need the data to never be stored on a file on the local machine, and dealt with entirely from memory.

Any replies appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: interesting problem. scp and sftp refuse to send /proc/self/fd/0 because it's not a regular file...

Comment: If you weren't so tied to bash, this would be trivially done in Python with paramiko.

Comment: BTW, `echo` is a bad choice of tools for the job. Read the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, and you'll be horrified at how much it's allowed to mangle your data. (Have a backslash anywhere in your content? `echo`'s output is suddenly completely implementation-defined!)

Answer (score 4):

The multi-protocol client [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) explicitly supports reading content from a non-seekable file descriptor:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ some features used here are not present in /bin/sh

lftp \
  -u remote_username                 \
  -e 'put /dev/stdin -o /tmp/secret' \
  sftp://remote_host                 \
  < <(printf '%s' "$secret_data")
```

Note the use of `<()` as opposed to `<<<` (the latter can, in some situations, be implemented via writing a temporary file; the former will be a `/dev/fd`-style redirection on modern Linux, or may be implemented with a FIFO on some other platforms).

Answer (score 0):

Create `tmpfs` partition in `/etc/fstab` (not stored on drive, only in memory), store the file there and then use your described method if you really want to avoid storing the file into your hard drive.

I have set up this way `/tmp` and `/var/log` to avoid writing all over the SSD drive:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
none    /tmp/       tmpfs   size=15%    0   0
```

Comment: I guess the real requirement is that the data is not in a location that would be otherwise easily accessible. By storing in this location, while the data would be held in memory, would it not be as easily inspected as a locally stored file? Sorry I should have made the original post clearer about this requirement.

Comment: Certainly you can mount the `tmpfs` filesystem somewhere else, where nobody else can have access. This was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If it's permissible to use your own, hacked copy of sftp, you can use

```
echo "my secret data 2" | (exec 6<&0 ; ( echo put  /proc/self/fd/6 /tmp/secret | sftp user@remote_host))
```

The exec redirects the stdin, which transports your secret, to another file descriptor, in this case, 6. The second echo issues the sftp command to execute. It uses the `/proc/` magic file system, the /proc/self redirection to `/proc/<pid>` of the process that opens it, and the `proc/<pid>/fd/6` name of the file descriptor 6, and copies the data that it reads from there to a file on your remote host.

It would be much easier if you could use a hacked version of scp, this would read

```
echo "my secret data 2" | scp /proc/self/fd/0 user@remote_host:/tmp/secret
```

Now for the hack: sftp and scp make sure that the local file is a regular file, but the /proc/self/fd/... file descriptors are pipes. You need to disable the checks in the source code.

For sftp, you would modify file sftp-client.c: Find all occurences of `S_ISREG(...)` and replace them with `1`

This is quick and dirty and might leave you open to security vulnerabilities if you do not check openssh security messages regularly and recompile if necessary. A better way would be to use a scripting language with a well maintained sftp library and use that.