# Moving files from S3 to SFTP using AWS CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm wondering what is the most efficient command to move files from aws s3 to an sftp. I have hundreds of files so downloading it locally wouln't be efficient. I want to move it straight from s3 to sftp.

so far I've tried this command but it doesn't seem to work.

`aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file.csv - | gpg --encrypt --recipient gg@decrpt.com | sftp account@hostname.com:/data/sample_data/`

as the pipe keeps getting broke.

Comment: I don't think `sftp` takes data that way.  It behaves similar to ftp with PUT command.  You can probably use `scp` just as well since they're generally implemented by the same server (though can be disabled).

Comment: "I have hundreds of files so downloading it locally wouln't be efficient" a pipe from s3 to some ssh program downloads just as much as downloading the file locally, even though it doesn't store it

Comment: You might have a look at s3 storage gateway https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/file/s3/ for using an S3 as an NFS share.

Comment: This might help: [How to transfer data into remote file over SFTP without storing data in a local file in Linux Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33744703/3776858)

Comment: Any chance of avoiding SFTP? Is there another way you can provide the files to them? SFTP doesn't play particularly well with the modern data world.

Comment: AFIK, the sftp interprets its stdin as FTP commands. If it would interpret it as data to be uploaded, it would not know under which filename to store the data on the remote side.

Comment: @user1934428 only if `-b -` is specified I think, otherwise standard input is ignored  (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sftp.1.html). But it doesn't take file content, it takes batch commands (so PUT blah) which would require some sort of filename kind of reference.

Comment: @erik258 : I just checked the `sftp` which is available on MacOS, and it reads its commands by default from stdin; no `-b` required. In the long-gone past, I had used `ftp` (not `sftp`) on Linux, and it was the same. That's why I thought that current `sftp` implementations on Linux would also follow this convention.